# Issue with OleDbConnection.Open when Running as a Service

Tags: database, ssh, nant, oledb, ado

We have an Nant build script that we are running through SSH *(Cygwin & Open SSH)* to remotely upgrade our databases.  When the Nant script is launched through an SSH session, the following error is thrown when it attempts to make a database connection.  However, if I log in to the server directly *(using the same account as the service)* and run the Nant scripts by hand, the script executes successfully.

**Error Message:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   .Net Framework Data Providers require
>   Microsoft Data Access
>   Components(MDAC). Please install
>   Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC)
>   version 2.6 or later.
>   ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID
>   {2206CDB2-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A829}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   8007007e.

**Stack Trace:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC). Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later.
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2206CDB2-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A829} failed due to the following error: 8007007e.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.CreateInstanceDataLinks()
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.GetObjectPool()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.GetObjectPool()
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
at UpgradeDatabases.UpgradeDatabase.Execute()
```

After spending lots of time trying to track down the cause, I am stuck.  Here are some observations I have made:

- The script runs perfectly when I run it manually on the same machine (without SSH).  I can even run the script manually, with the same user that the SSH service is running under.
- Since the Nant script is running under the context of a service, the issue seems to be related to the User Profile.
- The script is executing on a Windows 2008 Server with .NET 3.5 installed.  I wouldn't assume that MDAC would be a problem here as the exception indicates
- [One site states](http://www.avianwaves.com/Blog/default.aspx?id=169) that it might be related to UPHClean (which is a part of the User Profile Service in Windows Server 2008).  I haven't been able to confirm that this is actually the problem.  I looked in the Event Viewer for Event ID 1530 and there are a few occurrences, but they don't correlate with each execution of the build script.
- I installed the [native OleDb providers](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b33d2c78-1059-4ce2-b80d-2343c099bcb4&displaylang=en) for SQL Server 2008 and the same error occurs.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can track down the root cause of this issue?  It really seems to be related to the fact that the code is running under the context of a service.  I've used Procmon to try to trace through the execution, but I haven't had any luck finding the culprit.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was definitely related to Cygwin + OpenSSH.  I ended up installing [WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) and my issue was resolved.  So for future reference, be wary of Cygwin + OpenSSH running on Windows Server 2008. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I also had the "The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC). Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later." error when trying to invoke my Windows program over ssh, but not when running the same program directly in a cygwin terminal on the server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise). I felt sure this could be made to work using openssh in cygwin. Eventually I found that it could be made to work if you sent the following environment variable in the ssh call:

```
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
```

So if you logged in like so:

```
$ ssh myuser@myserver -o SendEnv='CommonProgramFiles(x86)'
```

Then you should be able to run your program successfully. Note this assumes you have already configured sshd on the server to accept the environment variable. You can do that by adding the following line to /etc/sshd_config and then restarting sshd (net stop sshd followed by net start sshd):

```
AcceptEnv CommonProgramFiles(x86)
```

When AccessDatabaseEngine.exe (Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007) is installed (download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) it puts some files under C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files.

Comment: Just for information, on `bash` (Cygwin), there is a tricky way to [set an environment variable whose name contains parentheses as explained by Linda Walsh](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-05/msg00098.html): `env - "CommonProgramFiles(x86)"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files"`  Hope this may help someone searching on the web... Cheers ;-)

Comment: In windows 2012 server I used this CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on Windows 7 + OpenSSH (OpenSSH_6.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014) while running C# program connecting Access database.

I've added

```
export CommonProgramFiles="C:\Program Files\Common Files"
```

in /etc/profile file.

Hope this help.